# Confirming Original Rudraksh Bead

Tags: rudraksha

I haven't purchased Rudraksh Bead ever, but before purchasing the Rudraksh Bead, I would like to understand how to recognized its real one.

While purchasing the Bead Can I ask them for certificate which is tested

Before wearing should I check if it suits me.

Comment: There are many [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+identify+real+rudraksha+) on Youtube. If you are looking for identification according to scriptures, make edits accordingly. 1`While purchasing the bead can I ask them for certificate which is tested. ` - Everyone does that. Looks like an opinion based question. `Before wearing should I check if it suits me. ` - It is not an ornament.

Comment: Where do you stay? India or outside India? it's always better to purchase Rudraksha Malas as per suggestions of  a Shaiva Priest.

Comment: I am from Mumbai India. where do I find Shaiva Preist.

Comment: @SreeCharan The link `http://www.rudraksham.com/wearingRules` shows that there are some skin are allergic to Rudraksh.

Comment: @Mongrel Even Rudraksha Jabala Upanishad gives rules to be followed but still go to any Shiva Temple and ask priest by saying your date of birth. Anyone can wear five faced Rudraksha but for other Rudrakshas, there are some rules to be followed. Tell him the purpose, he will suggest you a suitable Rudraksha.